# SQL SERVER 2012 - IntegrationServices (Assign values to variables in 2012 SSIS Package)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis, etl, dtexec

Can i assign values to variables in 2012 using below command I have used the same command in 2008 and it works fine.

```
DTEXEC /SERVER"XXXXXXXX\SQLSERVER2012"/SQL"Mypackage.dtsx"/SET\Package.Variables[FilePath].Value;"C:\Test\testvariable.csv"
```

Wondering is there a different way in 2012 to pass values to variables dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did it work when you tried it?  There are several ways to pass variables to SSIS dynamically.  What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Yes it works in 2008..Am using the same in 2012 and the procedure which am using this command fails . It doesn't show me any error. What are the other ways you suggest to pass the values dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign values to variables using dtexec 2012:

**Syntax**

> dtexec /f mypackage.dtsx /set \package.variables[myvariable].Value;myvalue

**Example**

```
dtexec.exe /FILE "D:\TestPkg.dtsx" 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::FilePath].Properties[Value];"C:\Test\testvariable.csv"
```

**References**

- [dtexec Utility (SSIS Tool)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [DTEXEC package with multiple parameters](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8be2d7e1-8d65-4d8c-8710-70ea06c91f7f/dtexec-package-with-multiple-parameters?forum=winserverpowershell)